# Need help getting JS files to find JQuery with using Laravel 5.7 with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-mix, laravel-5.7

I am loading JQuery globally inside of the **resources/bootstrap.js** file like this.

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

I also have a tiny script to test if JQuery is loaded and I have confirmed that it has been loaded.

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (window.jQuery) {
      // jQuery is loaded
      alert("Yeah!");
  } else {
      // jQuery is not loaded
      alert("Doesn't Work");
  }

}
```

However, I have a javascript file inside of a view that depend on Jquery.

```
@section('footer')
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
@endsection
```

After running `npm run dev` opening the chrome developer tools and viewing the console messages for my application, I see the following line

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at foo.js:100
```

indicating that **foo.js** cannot find JQuery. I would like to keep JQuery loading globally and make it possible for other files to reference JQuery.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your webpack.mix.js at laravel root folder and make sure that you define jquery to be autoloaded

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
 });
```

after at your bootstrap.js file, check if it contais this portion of code

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

then you should execute this command in command line to compile js and put laravel in developer mode

> npm run dev

for last make sure you are including the jquery codes **after** the app.js call in your master layout (very important)

I had this same problem you are facing and it helped me. For more information I invite you to check this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix

Comment: I add the above code to **mix.autoload** in my webpack.mix.js file and verified that I have the try-catch clause in my **bootstrap.js** file. However, I am still receiving the same errors.

Comment: @CurtisColly Did your section footer is under your app.js call?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also tried moving the app.js moving app.js below the footer and received the same error.

Comment: Im not sure but worth the try change in bootstrap.js the jquery line to global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's in here.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

The JQuery library is being loaded inside of the app.js. However, defer instructs the contents of the script tag to not execute until the page has loaded. Therefore, my custom js files cannot find Jquery because it's not loaded yet.

Getting rid of **defer** and placing my custom scripts below it will make it possible for the scripts to find and reference JQuery.